# Use twitter API to aggregate multiple specific twitter feeds?

Tags: iphone, twitter, aggregate

I am an intermediate level programmer with almost no web experience. I have an idea for an iPhone app and am trying to figure out if it is a feasible project to pursue.

I am thinking of building an application that groups certain specific twitter feeds together into an app. I am wondering if anyone has done this before, and if it is possible to use the twitter API to retrieve specific tweets without having a user have to log in.

The user will not be replying to or responding in any way to the links, rather just opening the links.

Thanks.

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any public twitter feeds can be retrieved without a user authorizing their account. However you can usually only get a certain amount of tweets into the past. For instance this returns info about a user and their most recent tweets, just replace "screen_name=" with whatever name you are looking for

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=jsh2134
```

More can be found at the [Twitter API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: Thanks JiminyCricket...appreciate the info!